# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:1.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: arduino-nano, usb, raspberrypi

I have tried everything on this url

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165761/java-cant-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-localhost10-0-as-the-value-of-t

session output:

```
root@whale:/home/kermit# echo $DISPLAY                                   
localhost:1.0
root@whale:/home/kermit# cd dev/sht30/
root@whale:/home/kermit/dev/sht30# arduino --upload sht30v1.ino --port /dev/ttyUSB0
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:1.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:83)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:129)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:231)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:588)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:583)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:582)
        at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at processing.app.Preferences.save(Preferences.java:735)
        at processing.app.Preferences.init(Preferences.java:249)
        at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:117)
```

How do you run arduino in headless mode on a raspberry pi?

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem with the Arduino IDE, but if you want to do headless development on a raspberry pi, you might want to look into PlatformIO, which does not need a GUI and can be used from the CLI. (https://platformio.org/ and https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/core/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably a non-existant or stale auth cookie in your .Xauthority file.  This sort of thing happens when you're running your X session with one user but trying to run your X application as different user.  Doing sudo or su root (or really any other user) is a common way to get in that situation.  Running the IDE as root usually mean something else has already gone sideways.  The typical reason for that is you're running as root instead of fixing your permissions to the Arduino serial device file.

---

That said, if you want to run headless builds and uploads of Arduino projects, what you're looking for is [arduino-cli](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/).

```bash
cd /path/to/directory/containing/sht30v1.ino
arduino-cli -b arduino:avr:nano compile
arduino-cli -b arduino:avr:nano upload --port /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: What version is arduino-cli in? I am 1.8.13

Comment: I'm not sure offhand what the latest version is.  Mine has been installed for some time now, I'm not sure its version will tell you anything.  The thing is though, the IDE version and the arduino-cli versions don't necessarily need to be related.  And the version number that largely affects your project is the version number of the (AVR) core, currently at 1.8.3. It's version number is also only-so-related to the IDE or arduino-cli.  Run the latest AVR core with the latest arduino-cli and you should be fine.

Comment: Just to give you a bit more info, I just ran their installer script (the curl to shell pipe) on their page to install the latest.  `arduino-cli version` now reports version 0.15.0 commit 0a034d73.  Again, this number has not a lot do with the others.

Comment: It looks like you've skipped over the command-line for compiling, the first of two in the answer.

Comment: I can get the sketch compiled and export the .hex files but it won't upload https://bpa.st/HYXCG

Comment: It is possible you need to use the the specific cpu option for the "old" nano, which connects at 57600 baud during bootloading.  In which case your `-b` option would need to be `-b arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega328old`

Comment: I honestly cannot tell if it worked or failed.  https://bpa.st/OXPQ I think it worked but I see a failure. Yes, it is an older boot nano

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119262/discussion-between-timemage-and-brad).